# Action Center Toast Notification without Shortcut

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, toast

I've created a custom C#/WPF application that can send toast notifications that has an activator that can handle activation.  I'm using WiX to deploy the solution and create a shortcut with ShortcutProperty elements for System.AppUserModel.ID and System.AppUserModel.ToastActivatorCLSID.

Everything works perfectly as expected but I wonder one thing.  Is it possible to register the ToastActivator without creating a shortcut?  This program is going to be used on an internal enterprise network and I don't intend for it to have any UI.  It'll be launched by the Task Scheduler, check a web service and send toast messages to the user when they apply.

If I must have a shortcut, the best UX I can think of is to just diplay an about dialog and exit.

Comment: I created an issue in the github repos that was the example project for my solution.  Hopefully I'll get a response there or here. https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/issues/19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Application Model Microsoft has, any UWP feature like notification center, toasts etc can only be done by a registered application.

An application is "registered" when its added to the start menu with a link.

There has to be a valid shortcut with a System.AppUserModel.Id otherwise all the new win10 features do not work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/quickstart-sending-desktop-toast